# What is a golden bug in software testing life cycle?

Tags: manual-testing, terminology

What is a golden bug in software testing life cycle. Kindly help me understand what kind of bug is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [some random site](http://careerride.com/Testing-latent-bugs-and-golden-bug.aspx):

> **Golden Bug**: The bug that is occurred in every instances of the application with severity level high and with high priority.